# Are both the eth_newFilter from/to fields inclusive?

Tags: json-rpc, filters

Does anyone know if the fields are inclusive? The documentation doesn't specify, and I would assume that they are probably inclusive fields unless otherwise stated, but it would be nice to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick whirlwind tour of the filter code... (Instead of simply running some tests to output some logs.)

When we create a new filter the order of events is as follows. [`NewFilter()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/api.go#L419) in [`./eth/filters/api.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/api.go) calls [`newLogFilter()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/api.go#L211) which sets some variables to the values of `fromBlock` and `toBlock`, using `SetBeginBlock()` and `SetEndBlock()` in [`./eth/filters/filter.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/filter.go).

When the filter is invoked to output some logs, the callchain ends with a call to [`Find()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/filter.go#L74) in `filter.go`. This in turn calls [`mipFind()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/filter.go#L98), which contains the following line:

```
for num := start / level * level; num <= end; num += level {
```

Where `start` and `end` are the values we originally passed to `NewFilter()`.

Here the `:=` for the starting block and `<=` for the ending block imply inclusivity.

Comment: I tested this with Erigon's RPCDaemon and I cannot reproduce the end block inclusivity.